# App keeps crashing while initialising Worker with Dagger2 in Android 6.0

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-workmanager

java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.work.impl.workers.ConstraintTrackingWorker cannot be cast to androidx.work.Worker
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:1486)
        at com.mpower.android.lpincrm.workers.DaggerWorkerFactory.createWorker(DaggerWorkerFactory.kt:38)
        at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:83)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:242)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:136)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Error is occurring on the first line of `createWorker()`:

```
override fun createWorker(appContext: Context, workerClassName: String, workerParameters: WorkerParameters): ListenableWorker? {
        val workerclass = Class.forName(workerClassName).asSubclass(Worker::class.java)
        val constructor = workerclass.getDeclaredConstructor(Context::class.java, WorkerParameters::class.java)
        val instance = constructor.newInstance(appContext, workerParameters)


    when (instance) {
        is MetaWorker -> {
            instance.treatmentMetaRepository = foo
            instance.newsRepository = foo1
            instance.geoDataRepository = foo2
            instance.medicineMetaRepository = foo3
            instance.preferenceUtil = preferenceUtil
        }
        is NotificationSchedulerWorker -> {
            instance.notificationRepository = notification
        }
        is SyncWorker -> {
            instance.syncAPIs = syncAPI
            instance.registrationAPI = registrationAPI
            instance.preferenceUtil = preferenceUtil
            instance.treatmentRepository = treatmentRepository
            instance.medicineRepository = medicineRepository
            instance.medicineDetailsRepository = medicineDetailsRepository
            instance.collectionRepository = collectionRepository
            instance.newVisitRepository = newVisitRepository
            instance.dueReceiptRepository = dueReceiptRepository
            instance.transportationRepository = transportationRepository  
        }
    }
    return instance
}
```

My worker version:

```
def work_version = "2.3.4"
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_version"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WorkerFactory` incorrectly assumes that every `ListenableWorker` subclass created by the app is also a `Worker` subclass.  It turns out that the `WorkManager` library contains some exceptions to this rule, which are used as internal implementation details.

The fix is to treat the passed worker classes as subclasses of `ListenableWorker`, not `Worker`.

```
val workerclass = Class.forName(workerClassName).asSubclass(ListenableWorker::class.java)
```

Comment: Though all the ListenableWorker classes used in my app have extended only the Worker class and this error occurs in a specific device (no error in other devices), your solution stopped the crashes. Thanks. Can you explain a bit more why did this not occur in other devices?

Comment: @tahsinRupam According to the comments in the source code, `ConstraintTrackingWorker` is used in API level 23-25 (Android 6.0 - 7.1) when the constraints include `requiresBatteryNotLow` or `requiresStorageNotLow`.  Those constraints were not available in `JobScheduler` until Android 8.